# What is the simplest way to override BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint in SpringSecurity 4?

Tags: spring-security, spring-security4

I was not able to find on SO the answer (e.g. here.
[Spring Security: Commence method in class extending BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint no being called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23314902/spring-security-commence-method-in-class-extending-basicauthenticationentrypoin))

I just want to override BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint without override other filters and other staff:

```
<bean id="authenticationEntryPoint" name="authenticationEntryPoint"
      class="com.myclass.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="realmName" value="myapp" />
</bean>
```

Unfortunately, it does not work and I need to configure filter.

```
<security:http auto-config="true" ..
<sec:custom-filter ref="basicAuthenticationFilter"
                                before="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />

</sec:http>

<bean id="basicAuthenticationFilter"
      class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter">
    <constructor-arg name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    <constructor-arg name="authenticationEntryPoint" ref="authenticationEntryPoint" />
</bean>
```

Then I have this warning.

```
WARN 2015-10-29 09:44:05,330 [localhost-startStop-1::DefaultFilterChainValidator] [user:system] Possible error: Filters at position 2 and 3 are both instances of org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter
```

Therefore I need to disable auto-config but I do not want to do it:

```
<security:http auto-config="false" ...
```

What is the simplest way to override BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint in SpringSecurity 4?

Comment: Is it about a REST authentication ?

Comment: It is REST authentication, but the question is general.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works for me with Spring Security 3 (I think it should work for Spring 4), without configuring any filter :

```
public class CustomBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint extends BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void commence(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, final AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {

        response.setStatus( HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
    }
}
```

**Update :**

CustomBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint is a Spring Bean. You have to tell Spring about it. Like in your post (I've just changed its name in my answer) :

```
<bean id="authenticationEntryPoint" name="authenticationEntryPoint"
      class="com.myclass.CustomBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="realmName" value="myapp" />
</bean>
```

You need also to tell Spring Security to use this bean as entry point instead of default one :

```
<security:http entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint" ...
```

Default configuration redirect the client to a login page when not authenticated. When you override this default behaviour, you only send a 401 code status (unauthenticated) and you don't redirect the client.

Comment: Do you use any annotations? How it can work without a configuration?

Comment: Thank you for your help! I was able to configure authenticationEntryPoint at http element:

`<http entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint">`

Please note, that it configure authenticationEntryPoint of ExceptionTranslationFilter. To complete the solution I configured authenticationEntryPoint at http-basic element (configuration of BasicAuthenticationFilter)
`<http-basic entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint"/>`

Comment: You're welcome. I didn't configure any filter and it works for me. Glad it works.

Comment: It will not work if you will provide wrong credentials.

Comment: You need to override the SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler to handle authentication failure.

Comment: authentication-failure-handler-ref is configuration of <form-login> authentication:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/appendix-namespace.html

To configure BasicAuthenticationFilter you need to configure <http-basic entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint"/>

Please note that I know SpringSecurity pretty well just you point me to configuration that I missed (documentation of http-basic is missed).
I have added the full answer below.

Answer (score 3):

Full solution:

1)  configure authenticationEntryPoint at http element:

```
<http entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint" ...>
</http>
```

It configures authenticationEntryPoint of ExceptionTranslationFilter.

2) configure authenticationEntryPoint at http-basic element

```
<http-basic entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint"/>
```

It configures authenticationEntryPoint of BasicAuthenticationFilter